# Is the "super" keyword deprecated in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy in Android and I suddenly saw that the super is deprecated? If it is, then how do you call the parent's method in contrast to the child's method?

Comment: Is it `super` that's deprecated, or the actual method you were calling on the super?

Comment: I would say that deprecated is a superclass's constructor which you are calling from your class via `super`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super keyword is not deprecated. It sounds like the method/constructor you are calling on the super class is deprecated.

Check the documentation/source code for the super class you are extending.